# Spock unit test works but mvn test don't

Tags: maven, junit4, spock

How come running a unit test in STS works and but **mvn test** in bash gives produces an error. Groovy Libraries are in the classpath. I'm also curious how mvn test differs from spock test. Can't mvn test pick's up spock test?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project purple: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
[ERROR]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
[ERROR]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.loadClass(DefaultScanResult.java:131)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:95)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:222)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:107)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR]     ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>purple</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <gmaven-plugin.version>1.4</gmaven-plugin.version>
        <groovy.version>2.4.0</groovy.version>
        <spock.core.version>1.0-groovy-2.4</spock.core.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.class</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the gmaven-plus plugin, also your groovy libraries are quite outdated:

```
<plugin>
        <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn more about this plugin, 
        visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Checkout the official [spock-example](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example) project for a working configuration.